# Animated short about a butterfly that kills a butterfly hunter?

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I saw this short back in the 70's or early 80's, possibly on PBS. I've checked collections of shorts like Spike & Mike's and Alive! From Off Center but haven't been able to find it.

The plot is simple: a man runs around in a field with a giant net, catching butterflies, putting them in jars of ether to kill them, then mounting them. A giant butterfly comes along and he chases it, but it grabs him instead and flies off with him to a cave, where it impales him on a stalactite just as he pinned small butterflies.

I recall the art style being very simple, with thin lines, a very 70's sort of style, with the man not colored in and a plain background. The killer giant butterfly was colored in, and the patterns on its wings might have been animated in a hypnotic style.

Comment: [Butterfly](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0820033/) comes close, but doesn't match everything you remember.

Comment: It does have a similar story, but the art style isn't at all the same and it lacks the gruesome ending.

Comment: This does appear to have been shown on PBS in the 1977-1980 time frame.  [This review on IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/review/rw2676832/?ref_=tt_urv) talks about this specific short being shown on the "International Festival of Animation" show.  [Someone on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=25Yncg8HVhU&lc=Ughh4tHG0IrHEHgCoAEC.7-H0Z7-RYrk9BxoPba8fVm) is looking for it too.  Unfortunately I haven't found any information about what shorts were featured on the show.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, seems that answer is [Kolekcionar (Milan Blažeković, 1971.)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kW7dv1E2mwg), with that same ending
[image]

> He is a collector. He enthusiastically collects butterflies. His only
> goal in life is – a collection. However, one specimen is missing. He
> decided to go hunting. He has found the last exemplary that is
> supposed to complete his collection. The hunt begins.

Answer [was posted by AlbertusGLupus in the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=25Yncg8HVhU&lc=Ughh4tHG0IrHEHgCoAEC.7-H0Z7-RYrk9BxoPba8fVm) linked by
DavidW in the comments to the question:

> @AlbertusGLupus 7 months ago  @brentcanfield8883  [Kolekcionar (Milan
> Blažeković, 1971.):](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kW7dv1E2mwg)

Comment: Wow! Impaled...er, nailed it!

Comment: Awesome!!!!! Thank you so much!