# Comic where an astronaut who had been a butterfly collector on earth was later chased by giant alien butterfly-like creatures

Tags: story-identification, comics, aliens

I read a comic in the mid 80s (maybe a reprint?) where an astronaut who had been a butterfly collector on Earth was later chased by giant alien butterfly-like creatures with nets on another planet. The alien butterfly creatures had human-like arms, and were cyclopean.

It was English-language, staple-bound, American format, and I presume it was American (or else a pastiche or tribute to 50s (?) American science fiction comics). It was on sale in the UK. Details otherwise hazy as I was a kid when I read it.

Any help identifying the comic greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Was this in magazine or graphic anthology form?  Large format glossy, pulp, hardback or staple bound, etc.?  What language and what country?

Comment: English-language, staple-bound, American format, and I presume it was American (or else a pastiche or tribute to  50s (?) American science fiction comics). It was on sale in the UK. Details otherwise hazy as a kid when I read it. Thanks for reply.

Comment: Similar question (not the same, is looking for animation, not comic): https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/239080/animated-short-about-a-butterfly-that-kills-a-butterfly-hunter

Comment: That animation description sounds very similar - is the plot a trope of some kind ?... But the comic's plot was definitely based on an astro/cosmonaut who gets his comeuppance on the alien world for his butterfly hunting activities on earth, so not identical. The alien butterfly creatures had human-like arms, and were cyclopean.

Comment: Pretty much any bizarre graphic-format magazine-type comic is likely to have been *Heavy Metal* -- but they ran for many years, published hundreds (thousands?) of stories, some just a couple pages, some long-running serials.  Art was in a broad range of styles, many of the stories were translated from French (origin of the magazine) or other European languages.  Makes it really hard to narrow down unless someone remembers the specific story (like the ones that went into the two movies, for instance).

Comment: Thanks Zeiss - I was too young to have seen Heavy Metal at the time. You're right that it could be from anywhere (and the premise seems to have been used multiple times as well). It stood out as being very American, 50s sci-fi (among the predominance of UK comics in the newsagents at the time), and though I was probably too young to really mark the distinction between the authentic kind and tribute/derivative/pastiche of that kind of work, it was in the smaller US format which was less common in small local shops at the time.

Comment: @Lowry You seem to have accidentally created two accounts. If you [contact support](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/contact), they can merge your accounts for you and you'll be able to comment on answers again.

Answer (score 3):

This one from [Misty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misty_(comics)) comic #12 is very similar to what you remember.  Not an astronaut, and not a cyclops, but that might be due to faulty memory. It does have human arms, at least.  (UK comic. Mid 1978, maybe you saw a reprint)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks Pete.
No, that's not the one - it was definitely a male astronaut, with an aesthetic of the 50s or 40s vision of the future. Thanks for showing the Misty issue and story, though - the scenario does seem to have multiple lives ! (Is that a Pat Mills version ?...)